Does anyone recognize this movie and what is the name
Looking for a movie i think its in Mexico.There's an election campaign. The Campaign manager's are American and are rivals.

You will need much more details than this.

I think the film is Our Brand is Crisis.
A 2015 release starring Sandra Bullock and Billy Bob Thornton. The IMDB synopsis is as follows:

In 2002, Bolivian politician Pedro Gallo hires American James Carville's political consulting firm, Greenberg Carville Shrum, to help him win the 2002 Bolivian presidential election. GCS brings in Jane Bodine to manage the campaign in Bolivia. Battling her arch nemesis, the opposition's political consultant Pat Candy.


That's it dude thanks a lot.
